# check if file is downloaded in temp in GCF from GCS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Im making video encoder using GCF

that downloads video file from gcs to /tmp and encode it by ffmpeg.

I want to ask how to check if file is downloaded in tmp?

I tried console.log(process.cwd()) but tmp folder is not displayed

```
exports.encodeVideo = async (req, res) => {

 mkdirp('/tmp')

 storage.bucket('video-bucket').file('raw/samplevideo.mp4').download({ 
 destination:'encoded/samplevideo.mp4' })

ffmpeg........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`download` method is async, and so the simplest way I can think of is to add `then` like:

```
...).download({destination:'encoded/samplevideo.mp4'})
.then ( () => console.log("done") )
});
```

If you take a look into the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download) there is possibility to add callback as well. I think it should be wise to handle errors/exceptions in the callback or using `catch` method chain after `than`.